# Why does Python's Decimal display some simple values as expontents and how can I prevent it?

Tags: python, decimal

I understand the value of exponents, but typically when displaying decimal values to an end user, it's easier for the layman to understand normal decimal values. When I perform the following, I'd rather the display value of the decimal be `50`, instead of:

```
>>> Decimal('22679.6185') / Decimal('28.349523125') / 16
Decimal('5E+1')
```

Is this possible without quantizing or doing anything to modify the actual value? Also, why does it display a short value like this as an exponent and some longer values in their normal decimal form? Is this a product of division (irony intended)?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures

Comment: `Decimal('22679.6185') / Decimal('28.349523125')` returns `Decimal('8E+2')`, but in theory the result should contain 9 significant figures. Why would it return only 1 significant figure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See: [Significant figures in the decimal module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144218/significant-figures-in-the-decimal-module) (which admittedly tells you to use .quantize()).  The main problem is that you must keep track of the number of significant digits manually.

Comment: I don't think anyone else understood the question I was asking, which was how to display the decimal normally (without an exponential representation of it), so I appreciate your answer, even though it isn't what I was hoping to hear :)

Comment: Ah ... in that case, you might want to start with `.quantize()`, then go through `.as_tuple()` and format it manually.  This is kind of a pain in the butt but is what I do in my "money" module, which I plan to clean up someday and put on github or something. :-)  (However I'm doing formatting with optional leading or trailing CR, DB, parentheses, and all the other accounting things, and I even handle Indian Rupee formatting with lakh and crore.)

Comment: Also: if your python is new enough (2.7), the `'{:f}'.format()` method (@wim below) works great.  If not ... (I'm stuck with python back to 2.5 if not earlier, so, yeah :-) )

Answer (score 2):

You're seeing the default representation, which you can change by subclassing `Decimal` and overriding `__str__` and/or `__repr__`.

Note that `__repr__` is just implemented like `return "Decimal('%s')" % str(self)`, but you should try and preserve the invariant that `eval(repr(d)) == d`.

Probably what you're more interested in is not modifying the default str output or the representation of the *class*, but just controlling the display format of an *instance*. In this case, you should just be able to use the [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec) features, e.g.

```
>>> num = Decimal('5E+1')
>>> num
Decimal('5E+1')
>>> print("{:f}".format(num))
50
```

Comment: Is there any reason not to use `'{:f}'` rather than `'{:2f}'` for `format`?

Comment: Not that I can think of, it may have just been a case of me being an idiot 6 years ago?  edited.

Answer (score 0):

Directly parse the Decimal to int or float you want.

```
int(decimal.Decimal('22679.6185') / decimal.Decimal('28.349523125') / 16)
```

or

```
float(decimal.Decimal('22679.6185') / decimal.Decimal('28.349523125') / 16)
```

22679.6185 / 28.349523125 is exactly equals 800. and it shows Decimal("8E2") without anything wrong.

the precision depends on the context  object. check it by using "decimal.getcontext()".It looks like following:

```
Context(prec=28, rounding=ROUND_HALF_EVEN, ....)
```

the "prec" is what you want. Try this.

```
 decimal.Decimal("42.5") / decimal.Decimal("37.1")
```

It results in 28 significant figures.