# How can I read '0.00' as a number in Python while preserving number of significant digits?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How would i turn "0.00" into an int without getting `invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0.00'` error?

Heres my current code;

```
a = int('0.00')        # which gives me an error
a = int(float('0.00')) # gives me 0, not the correct value of 0.00
```

any suggestion would be appreciated!

Comment: If `0` is not what you want, what *do* you want?

Comment: @melpomene i want exactly 0.00

Comment: You said you want "an int", and `a = int(float('0.00'))` gives an int

Comment: What's wrong with the second one? 'int' does not have any decimal places.

Comment: `0.00` is not an int, it's a float. Integers by definition are whole numbers.

Comment: What do you mean by that? Do you know what `int` is?

Comment: When i change it to a float i get 0.0

Comment: @stackoverflown, ...and `0.0` is the correct representation. IEEE floating-point, as used by most major programming languages, does not track number of digits of precision.

Comment: Yes. Well, technically you get numbers that (when converted to a string) show up as 0 (`int`) or 0.0 (`float`). If you want `0.00` exactly, then use a string.

Comment: i think you have an underlying assumption here that i'd like to challenge. `0.00` is a valid "representation" of the number 0, but it is NOT stored that way, nor does it need to be.

Comment: `>>> 0.0 == 0.00:
True`

Comment: @PrinceOfCreation i get that, the question im doing requires "0.00" to two decimal places..

Comment: If the question requires 0.00 to 2 dp. surely the original string value is fine. If you want to print it, print the string. If you want to do maths with it, convert it to a float.

Comment: @stackoverflown and the point is, if someone asks for "0.00" to 2 decimal places, they are asking for a "string representation". melpomene hinted at it too. It is very common to use string formatting to display ints upto certain precision (with stuff like `:.2f` precision)

Comment: You have to learn to divide the data (`0`) and its representations (`0`, `0.0` , `0.00`, `-0`, ...).

Comment: Sounds good, thanks guys.

Answer (score 6):

If you need to track the number of significant digits past the decimal, neither `float` nor `int` is the correct way to store your number. Instead, use [`Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html):

```
from decimal import Decimal
a = Decimal('0.00')
print(str(a))
```

...emits **exactly** `0.00`.

If doing this, you should probably also read the question [Significant figures in the decimal module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144218/significant-figures-in-the-decimal-module), and honor the accepted answer's advice.

---

Of course, you can also round to a float or an int, and then reformat to the desired number of places:

```
a = float('0.00')
print('%.2f' % a)         # for compatibility with ancient Python
print('{:.2f}'.format(a)) # for compatibility with modern Python
print(f"{a:.2f}")         # for compatibility with *very* modern Python
```

Comment: For good form, perhaps suggest using str format instead of old formatting, something like `print('{:.2f}'.format(a))` or f-strings like `print(f"{a:.2f}")` for python 3.6+